# How to determine whether it is vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does the set of all polynomials of degree exactly $5$, together with all the constant polynomials，determine a vector space?

Answer (score 4):

Take $P(X)=X^5+X^2$, $Q(X)=-X^5$. Both are polynomials of degree exactly 5, but is it the case of $P+Q$?

Answer (score 0):

Define $V$ to be the set of all polynomials of degree exactly $5$ including constant polynomials.

Define vector addition by :

$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$,   $f(x),g(x)\in V$

and scalar multiplication by :

$(\alpha f)(x)= \alpha f(x)$, $\alpha\in F(the $$ field $ $ you $ $ are $ $ referring)$. Then verify the axioms of the vector space(if they can be, in the first place)

Comment: I would say: 'investigate whether the axioms can be verified'. Then the conclusion that it is *not* a vector space is left open.

Comment: @drhab, thanks, I added the last line before but somehow it got deleted.